# Solve the non-homogenous recurrence $h_n = 3h_{n-1} + 3(2)^n, h_0 = 1$?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the non-homogenous recurrence $h_n = 3h_{n-1} + 3(2)^n, h_0 = 1$.

I can see that the solution to the homogenous $h_n = 3h_{n-1}$ is clearly $h_n = 3^n$. That being said, I have no idea how to solve $h_n - 3h_{n-1} = 3(2)^n$: I assume it's some solution of the sort $(c_1n + c_2)(2)^n$, but I don't know where we'd go from here! Can anyone give advice?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MSE!

You could always use [generating functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWspH-1Qxew), but that machinery isn't necessary here. Instead, there's a standard trick. Write

$$t_n = \frac{h_n}{2^n}$$

Then after dividing both sides by $2^n$ your recurrence becomes

$$t_n = \frac{3}{2}t_{n-1} + 3$$

Do you see how to solve this recurrence for $t$? Do you see how that will solve your original problem too?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm not sure I see what you're getting at, though :(

Comment: The recurrence $t_n$ is simpler because it has only constant coefficients. There are lots of methods for solving such recurrences, at least one of which was probably taught in class (assuming this is a homework problem of some kind).  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation#Solution_by_conversion_to_matrix_form) for one possible method, in addition to the generating functions mentioned earlier.

Comment: Oh no I don't know differential equations! We learned about generating functions in class a few weeks ago, but we were instructed not to use them here. We were instructed to try forms of $cn(2)^n$, etc., if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, note that for all $ k\in\mathbb{N} $, we have : \begin{aligned}h_{n-k}&=3h_{n-k-1}+3\times 2^{n-k}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3^{k}h_{n-k}&=3^{k+1}h_{n-k-1}+3^{k+1}\times 2^{n-k}\\ \Longrightarrow\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(3^{k}h_{n-k}-3^{k+1}h_{n-k-1}\right)}&=3\times 2^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{k}}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ h_{n}-3^{n}h_{0}&=3\times 2^{n}\times\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n}-1}{\frac{3}{2}-1}\\ \iff\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  h_{n}&=3^{n}+6\left(3^{n}-2^{n}\right)\end{aligned}

Answer (score 0):

Using @HallaSurvivor solution
$$h_n = 3h_{n-1} + 3(2)^n$$
$$h_n=2^n t_n \implies 2t_n=3t_{n-1}+6$$Now, let $t_n=u_n+k$ and replace
$$2u_n+2k=3u_{n-1}+3k+6$$ If you make
$$2k=3k+6\implies k=-6\implies 2u_n=3u_{n-1}$$ Solve for $u_n$ (simple), go back to $t_n=u_n-6$ and to $h=2^n t^n$.